# Schwartz kernel of complex conjugation

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the $d$-dimensional Schwartz space. Evidently, the map $f\mapsto \bar{f}$, taking a function to its complex conjugate, is a continuous map of the Schwartz space to itself. Therefore, by the Schwartz kernel theorem, there exists a unique tempered distribution $K\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d)$, such that
$$<K,(f\otimes g)>_{\mathcal{S}'-\mathcal{S}} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) \overline{f(x)}dx,$$
where $<\cdot,\cdot>_{\mathcal{S}'-\mathcal{S}}$ is the distributional pairing and $(f\otimes g)(x,y) := f(x) g(y)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.

I am trying to give a direct proof of the existence and uniqueness of $K$ without on the kernel theorem, but I am unable to. Any suggestions?

Comment: But of course conjugation is not complex-linear, so if your set-up of a "kernel" automatically produces complex-linear things, you can't proceed...

Comment: If you separate the real/imaginary parts of $f$ then you have a pair of real Schwartz functions for which you have a pair of kernels, one is $\delta(x-y) $ the other is $- \delta(x-y)$. As Paul said you can't do better for non-complex linear maps. Also the "kernel" of a distribution is always found from a sequence of $C^\infty_c$ approximations of $\delta$ it doesn't have anything mysterious (in the same way that we find the digits of a real number).